# Why is the get function of a list of integers returning a boolean?

Tags: java, list, boolean

I am doing a programming challenge I found online and write a function to help me. The function determines if there is a set of integers in a row, excluding repeated middle numbers, that increase by one in a list and returns an ArrayList of Integer's with the position of the greater number and the position of the smaller number.

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> stuckSet(ArrayList<Integer> list){
    int posIncrease = -1;
    int posDecrease = -1;
    boolean found = false;
    for(Integer i=list.size()-1; i>0; i--){
        if(list.get(i)+1 == list.get(i-1)){
            Integer val = list.get(i);
            posIncrease = i;
            for(Integer j=i-1; j>=0; j--){
                if(list.get(j) == val+2){
                    posDecrease = j;
                    j=-1;
                    found = true;
                }
            }
            i = -1;
        }
    }
    if(posDecrease != -1){
        ArrayList<Integer> returnList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        returnList.add(posDecrease);
        returnList.add(posIncrease);
        return returnList;
    }
    else{
        ArrayList<Integer> returnList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        returnList.add(-1);
        returnList.add(-1);
        return returnList;
    }
}
```

This is then stored in a list and I call the .get() function on it later and use that output to remove another number from a list. This produces a compiler error, "incompatible types: Boolean cannot be converted to int". However, if I print it out I get the expected output, "0".

```
ArrayList<Integer> stuck = stuckSet(copyList);
int posOne = copyList.remove(stuck.get(0));
```

I have not been able to find a solution anywhere, what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [ArrayList#remove(Object o) API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(java.lang.Object)) and you'll see:

> public boolean remove​(Object o)

> Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list, if it is present. If the list does not contain the element, it is unchanged. More formally, removes the element with the lowest index i such that Objects.equals(o, get(i)) (if such an element exists). Returns true if this list contained the specified element (or equivalently, if this list changed as a result of the call).

The error from the method here:

```
int posOne = copyList.remove(stuck.get(0));
```

makes sense since this method returns a boolean, not an int.

---

Regarding,

> I have not been able to find a solution anywhere, what am I doing wrong

Your main mistake was not going to the Java API as your first step

Comment: So, I've looked a little at the Java API, I'm trying to use,
remove:        public E remove(int index);
and I think that the error is in the stuck.get(0), because that's highlighted and is what cause the error message to come up, I'm using bluejay, and because, If i replace 0 for stuck.get(0) the 
int posOne = copyList.remove(0);
works just fine

Comment: Noah - your diagnosis is incorrect.  `get()` does not return an `int` on an `ArrayList<Integer>`.   And `remove(...)` does not take an `boolean` on an `ArrayList<Integer>`.  So the attempted conversion of a `boolean` to an `int` **cannot** occur there.  The diagnosis in this answer is the correct one.  If you don't believe it try doing it like this `int temp = stuck.get(0); int pos = remove(temp);` and see which line the error is on now.

Comment: It is also possible that Bluejay is highlighting the error in the wrong place.  Try compiling from the command line with `javac`.

Comment: Stephen - I ran both `int temp = stuck.get();` and `int pos = copyList.remove(temp);` and printed out the result, both of them worked and gave me the `int` type output. I ended up using `int posOne = suck.get(0);` and `int valOne = copyList.remove(posOne);`. This appears to have solved my problem.